# How can I get clicked input radio value from autocomplete to send in form to php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm doing an input with autocomplete where my user can select multiple users from database and I want to submit those select users in my form where action goes to a php file that does a INSERT in the database.

So this is the input, I want the selected users to show up in **p#selecionados** but user selects one at a time:

```
<form id="formCriaJogo" method="post" action="./components/insert.php">
    <label>Other users</label>
    <input type="text" name="autor" id="autor" placeholder="Write users name" />
    <div id="autorLista"></div>
    <p id="selecionados"></p>

    <button type="submit">Insert</button>
</form>
```

And this is jquery code to do the autocomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#autor').keyup(function() {
            var query = $(this).val();;

            if (query != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./components/search.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        query: query
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("input#autor").css("margin-bottom", '0');
                        $("#autorLista").css("display", 'block');
                        $('#autorLista').fadeIn();
                        $('#autorLista').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('input#autor').on('change', function() {
             alert($('input[name=autor]:checked', '#formCriaJogo').val());
        });
    });
```

Also, here is **search.php** that does the search:

```
<?php

include_once "../connection/connection.php";

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $link = new_db_connection();
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
    $output = '';
    $input = $_POST['query'];

    $query = "SELECT id_user, nome_user FROM users WHERE nome_user LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')";

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $input);
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id_user, $name_user);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $output .= "<input type='radio' value='" . $id_user . "' name='autor'>" . $name_user . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        $output .= '<p>The user your looking for doesn't exist.</p>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Now the clicked input type=radio value which contains users' id and name I want the user name in **p#selecionados** just to show them what he selected and also send id and name of user selected when submitting my form.

Comment: have a look at the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522930/setting-a-radio-button-based-on-jquery-autocomplete-value

Comment: this too might be useful:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data OR 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `array` in jquery so , whenever you select an option from autocomplete box.. put that value inside that array in jquery .I have use `checkbox` instead of `radio-button` in below code and whenever user select any option that data will get inserted in array i.e:`index` and when `insert` button is clicked the selected data will get display in `p#selecionados` tag and also an ajax will call to send your selected data to php page.Also i have added `value='" . $id_user."," . $name_user . "'` you can split this using `.split()` with delimiter `,` to get both `userid` and `username`.Sample code :

```js
var index = [];

//when check-box is changed
$('input[name=autor]').change(function() {

  //checking if checkbox is check put it in array 
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    index.push($(this).val());
    console.log(index)
  } else {
    //if uncheck remove the element from array
    if ((index1 = index.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1)) {
      index.splice($.inArray(index1, index), 1);
      console.log("remove");
    }

  }

});
//when insert button is click
$("button").click(function() {
  //clear the p tag content
  $("p#selecionados").html("");
  for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    //append all selected check box
    $("p#selecionados").append(index[i] + "<br />");
    console.log("userid & username" + index[i]);

  }

  if (index != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "yourphp_page_name",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        //sending array to php
        data: index
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //do something
      },
      error: function(error) {
        //do something
      }
    });
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' value='" . $id_user."," . $name_user . "' name='autor'>" . $name_user . <br/>
<input type='checkbox' value='" . $id_user."," . $name_user . "' name='autor'>" . $name_user . <br/>
<button type="submit">Insert</button> <br/><br/> Selected data :
<p id="selecionados"></p>
```

Then in your php side ,you need to get that `array` i.e : `data` using `$_POST['data']` and then [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your array and use it as per your requirement.

Comment: @soalrib by using `radio` you can only select one option in a `radio-group` because here you need to `select multiple` i suggest you using `checkbox` .

Comment: But I only had one user at a time. e.g.: I search for the user "John", there are 2 options, I choose the first one, next I type "Liam" and I choose Liam, that's why I'm using type radio

Comment: okay ,,this line `where my user can select multiple users ` in your above question confused me . Try to change `type="radio"` and check if above code works or not.let me know if there is any error .

Comment: Do you have slack so we can talk better? I'm trying to console.log something in this function and nothing happens.  $('input[type=radio]').change(function()

Comment: I was rethinking and it can be checkboxes but user has to be allowed to do the search multiple times and select multiple users at a time or only one @Swati

Comment: then above code will work if user select any option that value will get added in `array` or you can check if user have clicked on `insert` button and no value is selected just put an `error` message.You just need to modified above code as per your requirement.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-feistel-nvtbr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark Can you see there please? Nothing happens @Swati

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205533/discussion-between-swati-and-soalrib).