# jquery autocomplete. tracking values instead of labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have an jquery autocomplete field where I want to add multiple values in the same input field.  In the example I see here, http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple the value and the label are the same so things work fine with whats in the select event.  however, in my case, when the user chooses a name, I want the input box to show the labels, but I want to post the values when I submit the form.  to try to get around it, I added a hidden field in the form and have a separate array that gets the value, but my problem is when the user backspaces back out of the value.   Its still in my array.   Any ideas how to fix that?  or perhaps a better solutions?

```
var friend_data = [{"label":"JOhn Doe","value":"12345"},{"label":"Jane Doe","value":"123456"}];

$( "#friends" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        //source: friend_data,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                friend_data, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        delay: 0,
        autofocus: true,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );

            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.label );
            friend_id_list.push( ui.item.value );
            console.log(friend_id_list);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            console.log(this.value);
            return false;
        }   
    })
    .data( "autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var fb_pic_path = '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + item.value + '/picture?type=square">' ;

        return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + fb_pic_path + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Comment: I have looked high and low for something, but I don't see anyone else with a similar problem.  weird.   maybe I should just be checking the input field value (with the list of labels) on each keyup and if the number of commas in that list dont match 'id' array length, just pop the last one out? any ideas if that would be considered a good solution?

Comment: I'm thinking you could determine what should be in the array when the field is `blur`red out of but there are some problems with that too

Answer (score 0):

A bit reluctant to post this, b/c I am new to javascript/jquery and this cant possibly be the best way to do it, but if you are as new to this as me and are just looking for something that works, this is what I am using for now to keep things in sync.

```
$("#friends").keyup(function(event) {    
    var friend_label_count = this.value.split(",").length - 1;
    var friend_value_count = friend_id_list.length;
    if (friend_label_count < friend_value_count) {
        friend_id_list.pop();
        }
});
```

Comment: whoops.  noticed this falls apart if the user decides to type in a bunch of commas (dont know why they would but I guess they could), which doesn't break the autocomplete, but breaks this.  will fix that and update in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to create another array keyed on the label that points to the matching value, and populate it from within autocomplete's `select` function.

Rather than populating the `friend_id_list` data with each selection, I would create the list of values to be passed back to the server as part of the submit or blur by splitting the `#friends` entries and comparing to the contents of that index (hash).

eg: *(NB untested)*

```
var selections = {}; //instantiated earlier
var friend_id_list = [];
<snip>
select: ...
        selections[ui.item.label] = ui.item.value;
        ...

$('#friends').blur( function(){
    var entries = $(this).val().split(', *'); // in case space character removed..
    var friend_id_list = [];
    for(entry in entries){
        if(selections[entry]) friend_id_list.push(entry);
    }
    $('#myhiddenfield').val(friend_id_list.join(','));
});
```

Anything that doesn't match a previously autocompleted value will be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  If I am understanding this correctly, this compares by the label.  in my case, the user's full name.   my problem is that I have quite a few friends with the same name.   Thats why I actually have to try an append the fb pic.. so they can tell who is who.

Comment: I see. Yes, that's correct - it's creating a reverse-lookup on the label to recover the values. Hopefully it gets you along the way; the code is only meant to be an example of the concept. I'm sure it could be refined for your particular use-case. Be aware you can configure autocomplete to return more than just label and value if you wish. Here's one I prepared earlier that does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410091/jquery-autocomplete-and-php-populating-input-field-with-data-from-mysql-databas/7410353#7410353 This populates city, state and zip fields from a single drop-down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I agree its better handled in the select.  Will play around with it some more.