# Make MySQL items in autocomplete menu clickable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a jquery autocomplete menu, that show items related to a MySQL database. I want the echo to be clickable, but I don't have any idea how to make that possible. Any idea?

Thanks!

```
<?php
mysql_connect("***", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("***");
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select DISTINCT Username as Username from *** where Username LIKE '%  $q%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cname = $rs['Username'];
    echo "$cname\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Link to jquery autocomplete menu?

Comment: You want the link or I must link to...?

Comment: I need the link so I can understand your question better and be able to help.. Also could you show more on the client-side code (HTML/JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP needs to return a JSON array of references containing `id` and `value` attributes. Then the .autocomplete() should have a `select` function that is responsible for taking some action on the selected item - jumping to another page, for example.

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7410091/14750) might help you to understand what's required.

So assuming your JSON looks something like this:

```
[
  { id: "someuser", value: "Some User" },
  { id: "user2", value: "User Two" },
  ...
]
```

Then your autocomplete function might have something like this:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.item) {
        var href = "/some/url/" + ui.item.id;
        window.location.href = href;
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```