# How to get data from database using the letter search in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to get data while user is typing letter inside text field from database using PHP and MySQL.I am explaining my code below.

```
$searchData=$_GET['search'] ;
```

In the above line user is getting the letter typed by user and once one letter will be typed the according to key word search the data will fetch from data base.I am explaining the table below.

> db_name:

```
id    name     status

1      Raj      1    

2      Rahul     1   

3      Dog       1

4      Deer      1
```

Suppose user typed the the first letter `R` the all two names belongs to `R` should display and the single name will come when full  name will be typed.Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: first try some code yourself. don't ask for code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery autocomplete and PHP: populating input field with data from mySQL database based on selected option in autocomplete field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410091/jquery-autocomplete-and-php-populating-input-field-with-data-from-mysql-databas)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for

http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-autocomplete-using-php-mysql-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try MySql fulltext search, it should do the job. here is a bit of code that i have used in one of my project.

```
    function getMemberIdByName($query)
    {
        //global mysql connection
        global $connection;

        $searchData = $query."*";

            $sql = "
                    SELECT 
                        * 
                    FROM 
                        member_table 
                    WHERE 
                        MATCH(name) AGAINST (:searchData IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                    LIMIT 10
                    ";
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(':searchData', $searchData);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                return $result;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
    }
```

now use jquery ajax to call call this script with POST or GET value and call this function with the search value as a parameter.

you should be able to figure out the ajax part yourself.